# Calling another page's js function from different page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have 3 pages dashboard.html, documents.jsp, documents.js

in dashboard.html file i have a href link which should redirect the page to documents.jsp and call a function in documents.js file which included in documents.jsp file.

dashboard.html

```
<a href="documents.jsp?filter=somefunctiondocumentsjsfile"
```

documents.js

in this file i have an ajax call like

```
function somefunctiondocumentsjsfile(){
$.ajax({
    url : "DeleteDocument?docId=" + JSON.stringify(selectedItemsToDelete),
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        showDangerPopup(data);
        getOfficialDocs();
    }
});
}
```

How should I achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `onload="somefunctiondocumentsjsfile()"` attribute to the opening `<body>` tag in the `documents.jsp` file.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I want to call the function on click of href link

Comment: That was not clear. You can trigger a JS function on click by using the `onclick` attribute: `<a href="..." onclick="somefunctiondocumentsjsfile()">...</a>`

Comment: I think u are not understood my question, I want to redirect and call a function at same time

Comment: The onclick solution will do that: Calling the function and redirect to the other page.